# How can I record an audio file in Qt and read it in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, qt, audio, wav, pcm

I'm recording an audio file in Qt. After that, I have to read the file with MATLAB and analyse it. Qt likes to save audio files in .pcm format (i.e. .wav format without header) and I can't read .pcm audio files with MATLAB (format is not supported).

What is the best solution to transfer audio from Qt to MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since your .pcm file has no header information, you'll need to know the number of bits per sample you used to create it in Qt. A typical value would be 16 bits per sample, or a data type of [`int16`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int16.html). Then you can use [`fread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) to read the audio waveform from the file like so:

```
fid = fopen('your_file.pcm', 'r');
audioWaveform = fread(fid, Inf, 'int16');
fclose(fid);
```

If you then want to do any processing, you will likely need to provide other pieces of information from when you created it in Qt, like the sampling frequency.

Comment: Hello gnovice! Thank you for answer! I have following options of my PCM file: samp_rate=44100
channel=1
samp_size=24
codec=Audio/PCM
byte_order=QAudioFormat::LittleEndian
sample_type=QAudioFormat::SignedInt
How can I enter this information and how can I make FFT of this file?